# Row with Expanded/Flexible Widget with not looking as intended

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a UI design which is a little buggy. It looks like this (I disabled padding for better understanding):

[image: s]

It is but together by a Row containing a Flexible to not have all texts in one line and another where an expanded should fill out the parent row fully. This only works when the flexible is not active. How can I fix this problem so that the right part of the row is fully colored with beige?

Code of the Widgets:

Containing Row:

```
class TestRow extends StatelessWidget {
  //TestRow Displays a title and a text in a row to fit the apps UI style
  final double width;
  final String title;
  final String text;
  final String font;

  TestRow({
    this.width,
    this.title,
    this.text,
    this.font
  });

  final cell = (Widget widget) => Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 5, bottom: 5, right: 15),
      child: widget,
    );
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return cell(Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: testlightGreen,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          TestTitleDetails(text: title, width: width,),
          TestTextDetails(text: text)
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Left part of the row:

```
class TestTitleDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final String font;
  final double width;

  TestTitleDetails({
    this.text,
    this.font,
    this.width
  });

  final cell = (Widget widget) => Padding(
      //padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 5, bottom: 5, right: 15),
      child: widget,
    );
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Flexible(
      child:Stack(
        children: <Widget>[Container(
          width: width ?? 100 ,
          //padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Text(text,textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)))
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Right part of the row:

```
class TestTextDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final String font;

  TestTextDetails({
    this.text,
    this.font
  });

  final cell = (Widget widget) => Padding(
      //padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
      child: widget,
    );
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Expanded(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: testBeige,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(right:Radius.circular(10))
      ),
        //padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Text(text),
      ));
  }
}
```

EDIT: I think I would need to set height and width of the right sided container manually depending on the flex value given on the left side (Without the Expanded). I figured by testing that a size of 42 would fit 2 lines of the left side. I am now looking for a function that will let me allow to determine when there will be 2 lines on the left side to make the right side higher

Comment: Can you remove, `crossAxisAlignment` and `mainAxisAlignemnt` from `Row()`, and let me know what happens? Also, remove one, and see the result too, and same for the other.

Comment: Make the `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max` and set the Container on the right to have `width: double.infinity`.

Comment: It all get slightly to the left, but seemingly nothing else changed https://imgur.com/a/X8kuJGD

Comment: Updated my post: https://imgur.com/a/X8kuJGD